# Программа не удаляет подстроку в строке Python

Tags: python

```
l = [1]
string = str(l)
string.replace('[','')
string.replace(']','')
print(string)
```

Comment: на будущее - не используйте зарезервированные имена типа `string`, `int` и тд., а вообще у вас идет явное непонимание того, что вы делаете - синтаксис `[1]` создает массив из одного элемента и записывает его адрес в `l`, то есть если вы вы преобразуете `l` в строку, вы не получите `[1]`..

Comment: Я привёл конкретный пример что-бы негрузить вас всем моим кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [1]
string = str(l)
string = string.replace('[','')
string = string.replace(']','')
print(string)
```

Так как `str` в языке не мутабельны `replace` вернет новую строчку